# Issues while trying to get another class

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I wrote the `getPlugin()` method to be able to get the main class from another class.

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public Main getPlugin() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

But when I try to call it...

```
public class Arena {
    private Main plugin = Main.getPlugin();
}
```

...Eclipse gives me the following error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPlugin() from the type Main

I have used static, but static gives me issue's in a lot of different places, and I've seen that static is usually a bad way of doing stuff. Causes memory leaks and stuff.

I have tried using getters and setters, but those need to be static too?
The code I've been using is very messy and I'd like to find a cleaner way of accessing another class.

Comment: Static is not bad to use.  It has many use cases.  Static means all instances of a class share that variable or method whatever you declare as static.

Comment: If the method getPlugin() is not specific to an instance of that class then you should use Static.

Comment: You need to understand what `static` is and when it's appropriate to use. Static or not, you're also definitely going to need to *call* your `getPlugin()` method.

Comment: I've written bukkit plugins in the past, and it is a good decision to avoid a static singleton getter method for your plugin object. Singletons are an antipattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid using static methods, you need to pass variables as a parameter to the constructor of objects. In your example, it would work like this:

```
public class Arena {
     private final Main plugin;
     public Arena(Plugin plugin) {
         this.plugin = plugin;
     }
}
```

And then you can create an Arena from your main plugin class, and pass in `this` as a parameter:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Arena arena = new Arena(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because there already is a `getPlugin()` method in the `JavaPlugin` superclass, so when you do `Main.getPlugin()` you are trying to call the non-static one.
Also, your own method is non-static.

Here is how I do.
You have to use a different name and make it static. Also, you should initialize its value on `onEnable()`.

```
public final class Example extends JavaPlugin {
    private static Plugin main;
    public static Plugin getMain() {
        return main;
    }
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        main = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried changing getPlugin() to something else, but it still didn't work. It gave the same error. I've also tried initializing it

Comment: @Yupie Have you made it static?

Comment: Ah, no I haven't, but the issue solved, I used @Afforess' method to fix it!